# Returning template value from DLL class

Tags: c++, templates, dll

I am planning to write a ResourceManager class in my gameengine, so I can easily manage my images, music, models and so on.

class be like: (just a how it works then)

```
class ResoureManager{
std::map<cstring path,T> resources;
public:
<T> get(char path[]);
}
```

The idea was easy: store everything in a big container, and return via path the object. My problem is now, that I have to use a class with a templated container, so I can manage whatever I want in a future time. My main problem here is the `::get(char path[])` function wich should return the object. So far so good, I can instanciate some types for exporting, but are there any alternatives I can take ?

I am using MSVS Community 2015.

Comment: From your (broken) code example, it is not clear what exactly you want. But you may want to look at [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/any.html) (it would take the place of your `T`)as a means of storing objects of different types. Or maybe if all your resources can be easily converted to/from a string representation, [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) is also an option?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to return an object of type `T` (where the type is determined "on the fly").  That's not how templates work in C++.

A template, like everything else in a C++ program, is *input* to the compiler.  It will create as many kinds of `std::map<cstring,T>` for as many kinds of `T` as you *instantiate*.  `T` is just a placeholder for a typename that you provide.

Your `get` function seems to of the kind *return T, whatever it is*.  That's an old problem, so old that it was baked into C++ from the beginning: inheritance, virtual functions, and RTTI.  Classically, you define a type -- let's call it `resource_t` -- and derive classes from that one.  Each derived class implements the same set of functions.  You define your map a to hold `resource_t *` and, *mirabile dictu*, call the function appropriate to its actual (derived) type through the pointer.  That's how C++ implements the OO notion of *polymorphism*.

Unlike some dynamic languages you might be acquainted with, in C++ all the wiring of function name to object type is determined at compile time.  The program never discovers at runtime that a certain function is not implemented.  It's either there, or it's a compilation error.

If you try to flesh out the sketch you provided, you'll soon find it doesn't compile and cannot be made to work in the way it implies.  C++ does have mechanisms to do what you want.  The best thing I can recommend is a good book and some hours developing an understanding of them.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time for this answer. I know that it doesn´t work and I am familiar with this topic(Yes, I really am). In some different template classes (in my DLL), I used instantiation so far and it worked great. I just wanted to ask if there are any other ways to implement such a thing.